# Cloud Functions for Firebase - test with real database?

Tags: unit-testing, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Cloud Functions for Firebase unit testing docs states that :

> "If you mock functions.config() with a test app's real Firebase
>   configuration values, any writes to the database that your function
>   makes actually get executed against the real database. This may be
>   useful for debugging. "

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#mocking_database_writes

- i tried using the real config values in the test sample but the tests failed & no data was written to the database

sample code: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/uppercase/functions/test/test.js

- any idea how to achieve testing on the real database ?

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you have write access on your realtime database security rules

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your have authentication disabled for database access. However don't forget to turn back on the authentication for production.

Note: You could also use Firebase Admin sdk which will have root access to the database without having to disable authentication.

[image]